# Split Pane with tree element display using HTML5/jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have to prepare a split pane using tree element using HTML5/Jquery. The example will be some 
thing like that https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxsplitter/index.htm#demos/jqxsplitter/navigation.html

I am new in design section so waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

    var isMouseDown = false;

    $().ready(function() {
        $('#slider').mousedown(function() { isMouseDown = true; });
        $('#slider').mouseup(function() { isMouseDown = false; });
        $('#slider').mousemove(function(e) {
            if(isMouseDown)
                $('#panelLeft').width(($('#panelLeft').width() - e.pageX) +
                    e.pageX);
        });
    });

</script>

    <div id="mainSplitter"> <!-- table row -->
      <div id="innerMainSplitter"> <!-- table -->
        <div id="panelLeft"> <!-- table cell -->
          <div id="panelLeftContainer"> <!-- table -->
            <h1>Favorites</h1>
            <div id="favorites"> <!-- table-row -->
              <p class="noFavoriteFolders">No folders listed in Favorites.</p>
            </div>
            <h1>Folder List</h1>
            <div id="folderList"> <!-- table-row -->

            </div>
            <div id="viewMode"> <!-- table-row -->
              <div id="hslider"> </div>
              <a href="#inbox">Inbox</a>
              <a href="#calendar">Calendar</a>
              <a href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
              <a href="#tasks">Tasks</a>
              <a href="#notes">Notes</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slider" class="seamlessHeader"> <!-- table-cell -->
        </div>
        <div id="panelRight"> <!-- table-cell -->
          <h1>Today</h1>
          <!-- ... -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But my requirement is something like that.  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/igniteuisamples/jsfiddle-samples/tree/master/EN/HtmlSamples/splitter/basic-vertical-splitter/ I am unable to use it. Because it is a company product. That's the issue..